# How to create android activity that shows at specified screen position?

Tags: android, android-activity, position

My current layout displays activity that is not full screen (that's OK).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="100dip"
android:layout_height="200dip" >

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/hello"></TextView>
```

I also added android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" to manifest for my activity.

My 200x100dip activity now shows in the upper left corner. How can i specify position of my linear layout (or my activity)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as outer most layout for this. Ant then use absolute position in dp or `android:layout_centerInParent` or similar.

Comment: I changed outer most layour to relative layout, which parameter can i use for position in dp?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Activity´s outmost layout element (LinearLayout) will be placed in a FrameLayout that is the parent given from Android. I suggest you let your outmost layout match_parent/fill_parent in layout_height and _width and then center the content inside it with gravity="center" on your outmost layout. By letting the outmost layout being transparent and not catch click element it will appear as layout in the middle where elements behind is visible. If Im correct guessing that's what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

put that layout in another absolute layout in which you use android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="fill_parent" the other thing you can do is to use this: http://www.droiddraw.org/
you can move your elements around manually with that and it will give you the XML code that is used to do that. I found it very useful in laying out XML in android.